# Apache 2.4.9 Virtual Host on WAMP port 100 On Windows 10 503 error

Tags: apache, wamp, virtualhost

I keep getting a 503 error when I try to set up a virtual host. I can set up an aliased folder just fine, but no luck on the virtual host setup.

My hosts file looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost
127.0.0.1       appmarket.local
::1             appmarket.local
```

My vs-hosts file looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:100>
    DocumentRoot "C:/nanomarketvhost/local"
    ServerName appmarket.local
    ServerAlias appmarket.local
    ErrorLog "logs/appmarket-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/appmarket-access.log" common
    <Directory  "C:/nanomarketvhost/local">
        AllowOverride All
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:100>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/localhost-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/localhost-access.log" common
    <Directory  "C:/wamp/www">
        AllowOverride All
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have commented out the lines in the httpd.conf to load virtual hosts.

Comment: Did you check the error log and find out what is causing the issue?

Comment: What errors do you get in the Apache error log and if that is not any help in the Windows Event Viewer. Also why are you using port 100?